# Convergent improper integral exact value sought

Tags: calculus

I figured out through u-sub $x=\frac{1}{u}$ that the given integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln xdx}{\sqrt{x}(1+x) }$$ turns out to be zero. 
(I split the integral up at $x=1$).

Since the curve intersects the x-axis at $(1,0)$, it implies that the area under the x-axis (from 0 to 1) is equal to the area from 1 to infinity. By comparison, such area is finite and according to my TI in the neighborhood of 3.66 But now I am trying to find out the exact area. There is no elementary anti derivative. Is there some other integral trick that could be used to figure this out?

I am certainly open to complex integration, but I hope that it could be done without. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The exact area turns out to be $4C$, where $C$ is the Catalan constant.

Comment: @DavidH I am not happy with the answer but I am taking your word for it :) Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $-4 G$, where $G$ is Catalan's constant.  Sub $x=u^2$ to get

$$4 \int_0^1 du \frac{\log{u}}{1+u^2}$$

next Taylor expand the denominator, which is really just a geometric series.  Note that since $u \in [0,1]$, this expansion is OK:

$$4 \int_0^1 du \frac{\log{u}}{1+u^2} = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \int_0^1 du \, u^{2 k} \log{u}$$

Use the fact that

$$\int_0^1 du \, u^{2 k} \log{u} = -\frac1{(2 k+1)^2}$$

which you may show via integration by parts.  The integral is therefore

$$-4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2} = -4 G$$